# Reduce a number to single digit by adding its digits recursively

Tags: php

How to reduce a number to single digit by adding its individual digits recursively :

> Example 1 : `$n = 99999 >> 45 >> 9`
>
> Example 2 : `$n = 444444 >> 24 >> 6`
>
> Example 3 : `$n = 8888888888888885 >> 125 >> 8;`

then get equal to at last we want to get single digit.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or want us to do code for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_sum` and `str_split` into a `while` loop until the final value of `$n` has the length equal to 1.

```
$n = 4444;

while (strlen($n) > 1) {
    $n = array_sum(str_split($n));
}

var_dump($n);
```

Without `array_sum` and `str_split` you can use something like:

```
$n = '4444';

while (strlen($n) > 1) {
    $s = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($n); $i++) {
        $s += $n[$i];
    }
    $n = (string) $s;
}

var_dump($n);
```

Comment: Good one. Would be much better if some explanations added which would make it more understandable.

Comment: I want to do this through while loop

Comment: without the help of string function

Comment: @joy you can see my updated answer.. all I'm asking you is to try it yourself in order to learn coding.. asking for such simple algorithms will not help you to learn anything..

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this in a much more simple and elegant way, let me try to explain. For example if you have the number 53, you can divide it by 9 and it’s remainder will be it’s reduced number. Don’t ask me how I figured this out, I was just tinkering with numbers. So what you can do is use modulus, (53 % 9 = 8!) (517 % 9 = 4!). Perfect right? Almost, if the number is a multiple of 9 like 45 for example if you “modulus” it by 9 you will receive it’s remaineder which is 0 and we would expect 9 because 45 reduced to a single digit is 9. So you can just make a quick and easy else if statement checking for an output of 0, and if it’s 0 just return 9. Done! Whatever number you out in from 1 to infinty it will reduce it perfectly. Hope this helps :)